# Wordpress SQL Command to Set all posts by author John Doe to draft

Tags: sql, mysql, wordpress

I'm importing posts from another site. I've set all the posts to a specific author (John Doe in this case) and I now want to run an SQL query (in PHPMyAdmin) that gets all John's posts and sets them to draft. Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the database schema is the same as the one I found [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/images/9/9e/WP3.0-ERD.png), you could accomplish this with the following query:

```
Update wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_users
on wp_posts.post_author = wp_users.id
SET wp_posts.post_status = 'draft'
WHERE wp_users.user_login ='john doe' and wp_posts.post_type ='post'
```

If you know the userid of "john doe" you can use

```
Update wp_posts
SET post_status = 'draft'
WHERE post_author =12345 and post_type ='post'
```

You may also want to see this [support topic at Wordpress](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/set-all-entries-to-draft)

Comment: Worked like a charm, I knew the answer was simple but couldn't get it. Thanks!